# Excel Web Query Parameters

Tags: excel, web, excel-formula, excel-web-query

I have URL that has an available list of exchange rates and I want to add a parameter that takes a date format from Cell("A1") and places it in the URL.

I've tried setting it up as the following
Address = http://www.bank.lv/vk/ecb.xml?date=["date"],

however, I keep getting an error when importing

[image: WORKING URL]

[image: NOT WORKING URL]

How can I fix this issue, so that I can add the parameter from a cell value?

Comment: what value is in the cell you have tied the parameter to? The error message shows the expected format.

Comment: @jkpieterse The value in the cell is 20171808 - date format